# Execute a function every 30 seconds jquery mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a jquery mobile phonegap application. I would like to execute a function every 30 seconds the user stays on a particular page.

If the user stays on a particular page say page1 , i would like to execute a function every 30 seconds,

To put it in simpler words

If active page is page1 
fire getmessages() every 30 seconds.

How do i achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using jQuery Mobile 1.4, you need to listen to `pagecontainershow` and `pagecontainerhide` events in order to execute functions with *interval* based on page `id`.

Retrieve page's `id` on those events then use *switch / case* to execute functions as well as `clearInterval` when page is hidden.

```
/* setInterval function's name */
var interval;

/* 1) On page show, retrieve page's ID and run checkPage()
   2) On page hide, clearInterval() */
$(document).on("pagecontainershow", function () {
    var activePage = $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage")[0].id;
    checkPage(activePage);
}).on("pagecontainerhide", function () {
    clearInterval(interval);
});

/* Run function(s) based on page's ID */
function checkPage(page) {
    switch (page) {
        case "p1":
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                /* function(s) */
            }, 30000);
            break;
        case "p2":
            interval = setInterval(function () {
                /* function(s) */
            }, 30000);
            break;
    }
}
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/sP852/)**

Answer (score 3):

USE settimeinterval

Check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7W6/1/)

```
<div id="div2>
<input type="text" name="divText" value="q3"/>
</div>

setInterval(function() {
 alert('HI')
}, 30000);
```

**Time is in ms (1000= 1 sec)**

Answer (score 1):

You can `setInterval`.

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function myFunction()
{
setInterval(function(){alert("Hello")},3000);
}

$('#click').click(function(){

myFunction()

})

})
```

HTML:

```
<p>Click the button to wait 3 seconds, then alert "Hello".</p>
<p>After clicking away the alert box, an new alert box will appear in 3 seconds. This goes on forever...</p>
<button id="click">Try it</button>
```

Replace `3000(3 sec) --> 30000 (30 sec)` for your requirement.

Demo link http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/2c4ps/

Answer (score 0):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt7W6/6/)

[Reference Link](http://www.jquery4u.com/jquery-functions/setinterval-example/)

```
setInterval(function() {
  // Do something every 30 seconds
}, 30000);
```